# Strange border/background drawn in custom NSView

Tags: cocoa

I am subclassing NSView and implementing my own slider control (it is easier with NSView than NSControl I think), and thus I am implementing the "drawRect" method in that view.

I also implement "mouseDragged" method and calculate the position of the knob and then i call `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]` to make the NSView subclass redraw.

The problem is that when I call `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]` the NSView draws a grey background and border (looks like a rounded rect), but I do not draw this in the "drawRect" method and this border and background goes away as soon as I resize the superview.

What causes this background/border draw and how can I prevent it?

Comment: I found a way. If I call "[self.superview setNeedsDisplay:YES]" it all works. Is that a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that [super drawRect:rect] isn't performing well, but [super setNeedsDisplay:YES] does.

Answer (score 1):

In your drawrect method include this line:-

```
     [super drawRect:rect];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the code from the comment:

```
[self.superview setNeedsDisplay:YES]
```

worked, but not the one in the accepted answer. Just posting this for anyone else out there looking for a solution.